# Remove custom post type generated by a plugin (The Events Calendar)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, the-events-calendar

On my client's site, I had installed the plugin "[The Events Calendar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/)". I noticed after uninstalling, the event archive page still remained and I could not find a way to remove this page.

I have tried changing the `has_archive` parameter in the plugins files to be false and then regenerating the permalinks, but it still has not helped.

I've asked questions on their support forum and have never heard anything. This is problematic as the archive page is named `/events/` so creating a new page in the system with the slug `/events/` now shows nothing but this archive page.

Comment: are you actully positively sure you have uninstalled everything related to the plugin? If you go with FTP to the site do you see its files?

Comment: Yep, 100% sure, the plugin was deactivated and all files removed via FTP. I've also went into the DB and removed all traces in the options table related to %tribes%. Nothing seems to have worked for it.

They also recommended using a rocket plugin of theirs to another persons issue to remove traces of it and I did that as well. Also disabled and cleared caching just in case.

Comment: I suggest you make sure that your admin user has full capabilities. try this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Answer (score 1):

Custom Post Type registrations in WordPress are **not** persistent. CPT only exists as long as registration code had been executed in a current page load. If the registration is disabled the data will be in database, but pretty much ignored and invisible to WP core.

It is hard to guess what happened in your specific case. Most likely plugin had introduced *persistent* changes to the system, such as installing code files outside its directory or creating native WP entries (like a normal page).

Comment: I found the portion in their code that set an archive page for it, I just dont know how to reverse it. 

`protected $postTypeArgs = array(
   'public'          => true,
   'rewrite'         => array( 'slug' => 'event', 'with_front' => false ),
   'menu_position'   => 6,
   'supports'        => array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'excerpt',
    'author',
    'thumbnail',
    'custom-fields',
    'comments',
   ),
   'taxonomies'      => array( 'post_tag' ),
   'capability_type' => array( 'tribe_event', 'tribe_events' ),
   'map_meta_cap'    => true,
   'has_archive'     => false,
  );
`

Comment: Sorry, for the mess above, I dont know what tags to use to make the regular code block

Comment: This doesn't clarify the situation. Regardless of arguments they use for registration it should stop function as soon as you disable plugin and registration code doesn't actively run.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue was with the other event plugin I had, for some reason, it made the events page an archive as well and wasn't listing anything. Thank you all for your input.

-AJ